# will Installing git repo on current subversion repo work?

Tags: git, svn, github, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

I use local subversion/tortoisesvn for code repository.

I want to also use github on the same code.

Will simply installing the github repository and client etc.. work without removing the files from the subversion repository?

It seems to me like there should be issues. for example which client decides which icons will be shown near the files in the windows explorer etc....

Comment: Why do you want to do this? They follow completely mechanisms and will surely conflict with each other.

Comment: I want to keep the local svn which I use for history tracking while testing working with github to see if it fits my needs.

Comment: then I guess you should use a site that provides svn hosting…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the working trees to be on top of each other.

Look into using git-svn, which lets you treat your svn repository as a remote git repository.

Create a git repository, populate it with a pull from the svn repository via git-svn, and push that to github.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Github* is **service**, which *manage copy* of **local Git repository**
2. You want to use **Git**
3. You can have svn working copy and Git repository in the same tree, just create git-repo in SVN WC root and correctly write *ignore patterns for both systems (and maintain these lists)
4. Using bidirectional bridge (and one VCS instead of two) is more natural and easy way